# Application defined or object defined Error on End(xlDown)

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error ***Application defined or Object defined error*** when I run the below code. Error is highlighted at line `Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select`

I even tried using `Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select` but it still gives the same error. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Worksheets("Sheet5").Select

Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

My full sub-

```
Sub test() 
    Workbooks("OC.xlsm").Activate 
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Select 
    Range("C13:E13").Copy 
    Worksheets("Live").Select
    Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select 
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "test" 
End Sub
```

Comment: Your codes look fine. Please post full sub.

Comment: Sub test()

Workbooks("OC.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("C13:E13").Copy

Worksheets("Live").Select
Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "test"

End Sub

Comment: Any particular reason why you're copying three cells and then pasting that to a range on which you are applying xlDown ? Otherwise, you should get rid of all calls to Select, they are useless.

Comment: [This is how to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: And also [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: If `Range("B2").End(xlDown)` goes to the bottom of the sheet then you can't do `.Offset(1, 0).Select` from there

Comment: Thank you all! I figured out another way instead of using Offset. I used  a for loop to increment the rows so it updates the chart.

Comment: Its better to go from bottom of file to last row data and then offset: `Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select`